# Copy multiple files to its subfolders

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory, subdirectory

```
MainFolder
  |
  |--- Folder1
  |          |
  |          |--- Extra
  |          |--- picture.jpg
  |
  |---Folder2
  |          |
  |          |--- Extra
  |          |--- picture.jpg
  |---Folder3
  |          |
  |          |--- Extra
  |          |--- picture.jpg
  |---Folder4
  |          |
  |          |--- Extra
  |          |--- picture.jpg
```

I'm using Windows 10.I want to place a batch-file into the "MainFolder"-folder and execute it from there. It should copy every file named picture.jpg into its "Extra" folder.

Comment: Please specify which OS (platform and version) you are using. Windows 10?

Comment: Yes. Windows 10 10586.42 Build.

Comment: Sounds good. I don't do Windows scripting, but someone who does will probably come along soon.

Comment: Tag [tag:batch-file] implies Windows (I elide MS-DOS here). Anyway, this question is too broad. Have you tried anything so far? What part do you have problems with? A good starting point is `for` (open a new command prompt window, type `for /?` and read the help). Note that SO is not a free code writing service. Please be more specific. Learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm just looking for some script because I have almost 2.000 folders to do that. It would be a hard task to do it on each folder by "Ctrl+C Crtl+V".

Comment: I just figured out how to achieve that by command-line:`FOR /d %A IN (D:\MainFolder\*) DO copy "%A\picture.jpg" "%A\Extra"`

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [so] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead.